# What is the proper way to handle an array of one class in another class?

Tags: c#

Here are two simple classes to illustrate my question:

```
class Widget
{
    private int _widgetID;
    public int WidgetID
    {
        get { return _widgetID; }
        set { _widgetID = value; }
    }

    private int _categoryID;
    public int CategoryID
    {
        get { return _categoryID; }
        set { _categoryID = value; }
    }

    private string _widgetName;
    public string WidgetName
    {
        get { return _widgetName; }
        set { _widgetName = value; }
    }
}
```

And them the second class:

```
class WidgetCategory
{
    private int _widgetCategoryID;
    public int WidgetCategoryID
    {
        get { return _widgetCategoryID; }
        set { _widgetCategoryID = value; }
    }

    private Widget[] _widgets;
    public Widget[] Widgets
    {
        get { return _widgets; }
        set { _widgets = value; }
    }

    private string _widgetCategoryName;
    public string WidgetCategoryName
    {
        get { return _widgetCategoryName; }
        set { _widgetCategoryName = value; }
    }
}
```

How would I handle this situation in the most efficient way?

Also, so you know, I will need to nest other classes the same way below the Widget class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a read-only property of type [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Widget>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx).

- [Collection properties should be read only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327.aspx)
- [Use `Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx)